# How do I return only the distinct rows from an SQLite table that meet a particular 'group' criteria of a single column?

Tags: sqlite

This existing query successfully gives me all the users who logged in to our app at least once during the previous month...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, AppName
FROM "macanta_user_track_records"
WHERE "LoginDate" >= '2018-04-01' AND "LoginDate" <= '2018-04-30' ORDER BY AppName
```

How do I adapt it so it only returns distinct rows for apps that had, for example, more than 5 users login during the month?

e.g. If the current query returned...

```
Id      AppName
52983   wb439
64671   wg117
19879   wg117
66955   wk350
77045   ws230
54643   ws230
79669   ws230
77043   ws230
77639   ws230
77737   ws230
11404   xf417
```

The revised query would only return...

```
Id      AppName
77045   ws230
54643   ws230
79669   ws230
77043   ws230
77639   ws230
77737   ws230
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will do the job

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.Id, x.AppName, x.Type, x.FirstName, x.LastName, x.Email
FROM macanta_user_track_records as x 
JOIN (SELECT b.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.AppName
 FROM macanta_user_track_records as c
 WHERE c.LoginDate >= '2018-04-01' AND c.LoginDate <= '2018-04-30' 
 ORDER BY c.AppName) as b
 GROUP BY b.AppName
 HAVING count(AppName) > 5) as a 
 ON a.AppName = x.AppName
WHERE x.LoginDate >= '2018-04-01' AND x.LoginDate <= '2018-04-30' 
ORDER BY x.AppName
```

Comment: @peterdaly-dickson There is no way that this does whatever you think it does. It relies on an old, undocumented hack, that later versions of MySQL explicitly interpret 'incorrectly'.

Comment: Hmm... I ran this query and it correctly returned what I was looking for, when I compared the results against the original query. That's why I marked it as the correct answer - because it gave me the results I wanted. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: I'm sorry @Strawberry, I made a mistake. The queries are for an SQLite database, not MySQL. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: I don't know SQLite, so can't really help further. And who knows, maybe the above is a valid query in SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, AppName
FROM "macanta_user_track_records" as a
JOIN (
 SELECT AppName
   FROM "macanta_user_track_records"
   WHERE "LoginDate" >= '2018-04-01' AND "LoginDate" <= '2018-04-30' // To reduce number of rows,otherwise WHERE is not necessary
  GROUP BY AppName
  HAVING count(AppName) >= 5    
) as b ON b.AppName = a.AppName
WHERE "LoginDate" >= '2018-04-01' AND "LoginDate" <= '2018-04-30' 
ORDER BY AppName
```